# Como reajustar automaticamente itens, quando o item está visível ou invisível

Tags: android, android-layout

Exemplo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

...

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/docli_vol"
    android:layout_width="221dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/docli_text"
    android:layout_bellow="@+id/docli_prod"
    android:layout_marginTop="218dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="@string/ins_vol"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/docli_text" />

<!-- INI QTD -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/docli_text_qtd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/docli_qtd"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/docli_text"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="QTD:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/docli_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/docli_qtd"
    android:layout_width="221dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/docli_text"
    android:layout_bellow="@+id/docli_prod"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="@string/ins_qtd"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/docli_text" />

<!-- INI PRICE -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/docli_text_price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/docli_price"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/docli_text"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="Price:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/docli_text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/docli_price"
    android:layout_width="221dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/docli_text"
    android:layout_bellow="@+id/docli_prod"
    android:layout_marginTop="342dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:hint="@string/ins_price"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/docli_text" />
    ...
<Button
    android:id="@+id/docli_btn_reg_prod"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/plus"
    android:onClick="menuIni"
    android:tag="RegProduct"
    android:text="@string/regItem"
    style="@style/green_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/docli_btn_edit_prod" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/docli_btn_edit_prod"
    android:layout_width="205dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/docli_btn_reg_prod"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/edit"
    android:onClick="Edit_product"
    android:text="@string/edititem"
    style="@style/orange_button"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/docli_text" />
```

....

Quando o item está invisível não ajusta. Como fazer um ajuste dinâmico?

Comment: Favor traduzir a sua pergunta.

Comment: pergunta já está traduzida. Estando num forum em português as perguntas devem ser feitas em português e não em inglês @Jomar

Comment: Em vez de `INVISIBLE` use `GONE`.